# Error: could not find function plot in R

Tags: r, plot, knitr

I was trying to estimate an ARIMA model by using my own function "foo". The error code could not find function plot in R came in nowhere. really bothers me. Any idea how that happened? I have tried the `stats:::plot` still doesn't work.

````
```{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
require(forecast)
foo <- function(N, y1=1, p=0.8, q=1-p, seed=NULL, stepwise=TRUE, verbose=0) {
if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
y <- c(y1, rep(NA,N-1))
for (i in 2:N) y[i] <- p*y[i-1] + q*rnorm(1)
if (verbose) plot(y, type='l', xlab='time')
return (list(y=y, aa=auto.arima(y, stepwise=stepwise)))
}
v <- foo(N=100, seed=10, verbose=1); v$aa$coef
```
````

Comment: put `search()` right before the `plot` call and be sure `package:stats` is on your call tree

Comment: @MichaelChirico thanks. tried again. now it pops Error in search(plot) : unused argument (plot)

Comment: you didn't do what I said :p

Comment: Are you certain that `require(forecast)` is returned `TRUE`? There are many arguments *against* use of `require` in lieu of `library`. In this case, if the package is not available, the code will happily continue without a care (and without notice to you.) The only reason to justify the use of `require` (IMO) is when your code does one thing if the package is present (in which case you should `if (require(...))`), and something else if not present. BTW: it might be clearer to break out the plot-generation from the coefficient-return aspects of the code block.

Comment: In a recent example on my laptop, I have both R-3.3 and 3.4 installed. I'm doing most of my work right now in 3.3 until everything is tested, but when I compile an Rmd file it defaults to the most-recently installed. In that case, many of the packages I use had not been installed yet in 3.4. Ergo why I see a package as installed in one instance of R but it is not available when compiling the Rmd.

Comment: @r2evans  thanks for the input guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
require(forecast)
Loading required package: forecast
> foo <- function(N, y1=1, p=0.8, q=1-p, seed=NULL, stepwise=TRUE, verbose=0) {
+     if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
+     y <- c(y1, rep(NA,N-1))
+     for (i in 2:N) y[i] <- p*y[i-1] + q*rnorm(1)
+     if (verbose) plot(y, type='l', xlab='time')
+     return (list(y=y, aa=auto.arima(y, stepwise=stepwise)))
+ }
> v <- foo(N=100, seed=10, verbose=1); v$aa$coef
  ar1 
0.8946974
```

Your code works well.. It even plots a plot. So maybe the proble is with the loading of the forecast package.. Or try using stats::plot before plot not three colons but two.